# Optional dropdown Parameter in Azure workbook

Tags: kql

I want to create an optional dropdown parameter in an Azure Workbook.
Creating a dropdown parameter [with this guide](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-dropdowns#creating-a-dynamic-drop-down-parameter) is straight forward

Then the parameter can be referenced in KQL [as shown in the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-dropdowns#in-kql) with

```
 requests
    | where name == '{RequestName}'
```

So far so good, I now want this parameter to be optional and if a value is not selected in the dropdown to get all the results unfiltered, like I would get if the `|where` part was not there at all. Right now if this parameter is not set then I get a `Query could not be parsed error`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
requests
| where isempty('{RequestName}') or (name == '{RequestName}')
```