# Consider the where condition based on the parameter value in KQL

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I'm using Azure Log Analytics.

//Below is the Log Analytics Function (e.g Function Name is "TestFunction")
**SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns 

| where Level == LevelValue

| where PipelineName == PipelineNameValue

| where Parameters.DataSetName != "" and Parameters.DataSetName == DataSetNameValue**

Function call examples:
Case1: **TestFunction('Error', 'PipelineName','DataSetName')**
Case2: **TestFunction('Error', 'PipelineName','')**

This is a generic pipeline Query, this pipeline may contain parameter called "DataSetName" or may not as well.

If I'm passing empty value in DataSetName parameter - it should not consider the 3rd where condition and just compare 1st two conditions. Is this achievable?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71658102/6336479

Answer (score 0):

This could be your function in which for each where-statement either the input parameter is empty or if it is given it shall equal the column value:

```
.create-or-alter function TestFunction(LevelValue:string, PipelineNameValue:string, DataSetNameValue:string) {
    SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns
    | where isempty(LevelValue) or Level == LevelValue
    | where isempty(PipelineNameValue) or PipelineName == PipelineNameValue
    | where isempty(DataSetNameValue) or Parameters.DataSetName == DataSetNameValue
}
```